# how can i connect to the console of another process using boost

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, ipc, boost-asio

I have two process. Ferst process create console window, second process shuld print some simbols in ferst process console.
If i use WinApi, I have `AttachConsole(DWORD dwProcessId)` function, is it possible to do something similar using boost?
The interprocess and process libraries have functions for attaching to processes, but I don’t understand how to use one console for two processes.
Something similar maybe can do with `boost::asio`,but i think this is not what i need

Comment: Why is this required? What are you trying to achieve? Normally, I'd either  let "process 2" own the console and tell it what to output, *or* ask 'process 2" to transfer ownership of its console window to me. Also, no portable console exists so your solution will be windows specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.